# Jqgrid in a asp.net page in a subfolder not working due to js and css file paths

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have implemented jqgrid within asp.net 3.5 vs2010. It is working fine as long as the asp.net page is onthe root folder, but when I move the page to a subfolder it tries to look for the js and css files with the foder under subfolder. The js and css files are in a folder under the root folder.

I am using the folowing code to reference to jquery files:

What it does is it appends the subfolder name to the path and the application is not able to find the js and css files. e.g /Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js

How do I reference the js and css files under the  html tag of asp.net page?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [developer version](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install#development_installation) of jaGrid you have to modify the variable `pathtojsfiles` from the [jquery.jqGrid.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/jquery.jqGrid.js) depend on the path where you place jqGrid on your site.

I recommend you to include all files listed in jquery.jqGrid.js instead of using jquery.jqGrid.js. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880564/what-causes-the-jqgrid-is-not-a-function-error/4880766#4880766) and [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-3-7-2-bug-with-ie8-while-using-jqgrid-debugging/#p21510) answers for more information.